# Would someone please help me understand this logic?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary variable that stores two columns of a pandas array, and it prints perfectly. However, when I assign variable to a template for json metadata, only the one row of the array is written to the json file. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around why this is happening.

```
for i in range(attributesQuantity):
    attributesCount = {
        "trait_type": dfM.loc[i, "trait_type"],
        "value": dfM.loc[i, "value"],
    }
    print(attributesCount)
    prompt_metadata["attributes"] = [attributesCount]
```

I'm expecting the the same value as print(attributesCount) to be assigned to attributes in prompt_metadata.json . An example of print(attributesCount) is

```
{'trait_type': 'Hair Color', 'value': 'blonde haired'}
{'trait_type': ' Sex', 'value': ' boy'}
{'trait_type': ' Eye Color', 'value': ' black eyes'}
{'trait_type': ' Race', 'value': ' human'}
```

whereas the json looks like

```
"attributes": [{"trait_type": " Race", "value": " human"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [pandas.DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), codes like `dfM.loc[i, "trait_type"]` should get the element of `trait_type` column in the `i`th row, and the print output would only be something like `{"trait_type": " Race", "value": " human"}`.

`prompt_metadata["attributes"]` in this loop, is reassigning `prompt_metadata["attributes"]` in each loop, probably you should try something like this:

```
    for i in range(attributesQuantity):
        attributesCount = {
            "trait_type": dfM.loc[i, "trait_type"],
            "value": dfM.loc[i, "value"],
        }
        print(attributesCount)
        if prompt_metadata["attributes"] is None:
            prompt_metadata["attributes"] = []
        else:
            prompt_metadata["attributes"].append(attributesCount)
```

Comment: Thank you! I think that I understand, now. Is there a way to do this without appending? All of this code in wrapped in another loop that is the length of json files being created, and appending attributesCount makes consecutive json files contain the previous output of ["attributes"].

Comment: @Norepi I don't quite understand what you mean. If this loop is inside another loop, and this inner loop is responsible for one json file only, you probably need a temporary list variable to store `attributesCount` and in the outside loop do something like `prompt_metadata["json_file_1"]["attributes"] = temp_list`

Comment: No worries. I just figured it out. I needed to clear the stored value in append(). I did so by ending the parent loop with prompt_metadata["attrtibutes] = [] . I really appreciate your help on this! @xunije liu